# Regex to get a particular string

Tags: java, regex

My String is like this -
`word1("word2").word3( "word4","{{word5}}", "sentence6","","word7"|"word8", word9 )` and except sentence6 all other are static words. I want to extract sentence6 by matching other words value.
I was using regex for it but was not able to handle `{{}}` and `()`.
So what should I do?

Comment: You should try to write your own code first.

Comment: Try to code it first, post a sample of your code, and maybe we'll be able to help.

Comment: *"So what should I do?"* - What you should do is read up on how to escape regex meta-characters.

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/hc1r56/1

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "\\}\\}\", \"(.*)\",\"\"";
final String string = "word1(\"word2\").word3( \"word4\",\"{{word5}}\", \"sentence6\",\"\",\"word7\"|\"word8\", word9 )";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the part where `"sentence6"` occurs from the opening double quotes till the closing double quotes, you could match the part that comes before it up until the opening double quotes `}}", "` and then match until the next double quote and capture that in a group `([^"]+)`:

[`}}\", \"([^"]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/FBCuQp/1/)

```
}}\", \" # Match }}", "
(        # Capturing group
  [^"]+  # Match not " one or more times
)        # Close capturing group
```

Use in java:

`\\}}\\\", \\\"([^\"]+)`

[Demo Java output](http://rextester.com/DBTB17477)